# Compiling python program using java file and reading input for python program from the file

Tags: java, python

I've stored my python code in file and then input is passed through input.txt.

```
    String rollno="13F127";
    String file="add";
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Python34\\python C:\\Users\\Raga\\Documents\\"+rollno+"\\"+file+".py < C:\\Users\\Raga\\Documents\\"+rollno+"\\input.txt");
```

When I run it using jsp file, it takes long time to load and output didnt come. Please help me with this.
I've read this process output using buffered and input reader.

```
    stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
```

Please help me with this!

Comment: How are you reading the `Process` output? And, have you considered using [jython](http://www.jython.org/)?

Comment: I'm reading it using input stream and buffered stream

Comment: In separate threads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Do not use redirections (<, >, or |) with exec!**

The redirections are read and translated by the interactive shells (here cmd.exe) where they read a command from their standard input. The shell then opens the relevant files and calls the program with redirected standard streams.

`exec` just does this last part, and passes the `< ...input.text` as two arguments to the Python program... that do not processes them and also passes them to the script that do not process them either! So the child tries to read on standard input, and keeps waiting here.

So you should:

- use ProcessBuilder which according to `Runtime` javadoc *is now the preferred way to start a process with a modified environment*
- redirect input stream for the subprocess to the file

More or less:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Python34\\python",
    "C:\\Users\\Raga\\Documents\\"+rollno+"\\"+file+".py");
pb.redirectInput(Redirect.fromFile("C:\\Users\\Raga\\Documents\\"+rollno+"\\input.txt"));
Process p = pb.start();
```